# Create singleton class in python by taking advantage of meta class

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I came across some materials online regarding how to force a class to be created as Singleton by taking advantage of python metaclass. The code snippet is roughly as below:

```
class SingletonMetaClass(type):
    _instance = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instance:
            # usually a lock is used here, but omitted for simplicity
            cls._instance[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

        return cls._instance[cls]

class SingletonBaseClass(object, metaclass=SingletonMetaClass):
    def __init__():
        pass

class SingletonDerivedClass(SingletonBaseClass):
    def __init__():
        pass
```

The Above snippet works perfectly for me - all instances of `SingletonDerivedClass` will be identical ones. However, what I found is strange is the line in `SingletonMetaClass` that `cls._instance[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)`. Apparently, the former `cls` refers to `SingletonMetaClass` itself and the latter one refers to the subclass, in this case, it will be `SingletonDerivedClass`, but inside `__call__`'s signature there's only one `cls`, how does python interpreter tell which `cls` refers to what?

Any replies would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the uses of `cls` refer to the metaclass. They refer to the instance of the metaclass, either `SingletonBaseClass` or `SingletonDerivedClass`.

Looking up `cls._instance` when `cls` is `SingletonBaseClass` finds `SingletonMetaClass._instance` because `SingletonBaseClass` is an instance of `SingletonMetaClass`, and looking up attributes on an object also searches its class, even when the object is itself also a class.

Answer (score 0):

"Create singleton class in python by taking advantage of meta class"

don't.

please.

This defines overkill.

So, before explaining what went wrong or your doubt, here is how you can define a singleton in Python, which can only be usd as a singleton, unless someone decides to use introspection to "create more than one singleton"- at which point the person could just as well abuse whatever thr mechanisms you have there.

Simply create a class, then create the instance that will be your singleton. Then remove the reference to the class from the namespace.
If there is code that would try to instantiate the class that should be a singleton, put a `__call__` method returning `self`:

```py
class MySingleton():
    ...
    def __call__(self):
        return self

mysingleton = MySingleton()
del MySingleton
```

If the code won't expect to instantiate the class, or ou need the singleton to be callable for other reasons: this  `__call__` is simply cosmetic. Actually, the singleton instance could have the same name as the class, and even the `del` statement is not needed.

Now, forthe part you got confused in your code: as far as any method in the metaclass is concerned, if it is a method that would be an "instance" method: i.e. take "self" as the first parameter, that first parameter refers to a class! (not the metaclass). So, we usually write `cls` as the parameter name when writting methods for the metaclass.

In other words, in the case of your `__call__` that "cls" is the instance of the metaclass: the classes themselves. Using the name  `cls` for the parameter in `__call__` does not magically makes it receive a reference to the class where the method is written (the metaclass itself).

If given your class you want to get a reference to the metaclass, just proceed as with any other Python object: use either the `type` call or check the  `__class__` attribute.

So the fix for your code would be, if you choose to ignore my advice to have metaclasses just for having a singleton:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls not in cls._instance:
        # usually a lock is used here, but omitted for simplicity
        cls.__class__._instance[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    return cls._instance[cls]
```

If you want the first parameter in a metaclass method to be the metaclass itself, the `@classmethod` decorator does that(but such modifier can only be applied for ordinay methods - other than "dunder" special methods, like `__call__` - the language expects `__call__` and others to take the instance as first parameter)